# Prevent Lightning Tabset from rendering a hidden overflow button

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-tabset, overflow

I notice that when using a `<lightning-tabset>`. It renders a hidden `<li>` which is an overflow button `'slds-tabs_default__overflow-button'`, with style `visibility:hidden`.

Can we prevent this `<li>` from being rendered ?

In the base component of the tabset, there is an api variable named `disableOverflow`. Tried setting this to `true`. But the `<li>` still rendered.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you tried giving it Style display:none

try this in js file:

```
renderedCallback(){
    let style = document.createElement("style");
    style.innerText = `lightning-tab-bar li.slds-tabs_default__item.slds-tabs_default__overflow-button{
        display:none;
    }`;
    this.template?.querySelectorAll('lightning-tabset')?.forEach(element => {
        element.appendChild(style)
    });
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have tried this, the style would not apply to the component. If I do the same in console, it works.                                                                                                           ```.slds-tabs_default__overflow-button {
      display: none !important;
       height: var(--slds-c-tabs-item-sizing-height, var(--sds-c-tabs-item-sizing-height,   var(--lwc-lineHeightTab,2.5rem)));
       line-height: var(--slds-c-tabs-item-line-height, var(--sds-c-tabs-item-line-height, var(--lwc-lineHeightTab,2.5rem)));
}```

Comment: @Akshay-Sharmax begging for votes/accepts (i.e. "please upvote and mark as best answer") is frowned upon here. It doesn't add any useful information to the answer. If your answer is correct and high enough quality, then it will naturally attract upvotes.

Comment: I've downvoted this because the information you've provided appears to be wrong. Applying a `<style>` tag inside of a tag in the body of a document was only possible for a few years, and was never widely supported. In short, your suggestion does not produce valid HTML (though browsers may be able to undo/reinterpret such a mistake so it doesn't break the page completely). Using the `classList` property (with its add/remove/replace/toggle functions) looks like the way to go about this.

Comment: @DerekF Actually was new to the platform and also a learner, thanks for helping out..
If you could provide a code snippet how can we use these classList properties in this specific case it would be a great learning